# MVC 3 default values in drop downs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a C#.Net MVC 3 web app and need to implement a year date drop down set similar to what is used on a credit card site for expiration date.  Select a month, then select a day.  I want to default to a value that is set in the web config file.  How do I set a default value for a drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Controller**

```
var yearlist = new[] {   
    new MyYear { Id = 2011, Text = "2011" }, 
    new MyYear { Id = 2010, Text = "2010" }, 
    new MyYear { Id = 2009, Text = "2009" },
    new MyYear { Id = 2008, Text = "2008" }  
};

var selectList = new SelectList(yearlist , "Id", "Text", 2011);
ViewData["Years"] = selectList;
```

The SelectList last parameter is the id that you want to get from the web.config and be selected by default.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("YearClass", (SelectList)ViewData["Years"])
```

Comment: @Romais....actually, it's not working for me.  I have other drop downs that work just fine.  They operate on a model property and so do my date drop downs however, they do not hold the value even though the property of the model has the value.  Any ideas?

Comment: @MikeTWebb please debug it and see if the "yearlist" has items. Also check that the model property that holds the text (the years) are the correct.

Comment: @Romais...the yearlis has items and the appropriate item has the Selected property set to true. The Modeal property is as below. Which I think is correct: public string DateFromYear { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Use [**SelectList**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx) - you can specify selected value in the constructor.

Pass `SelectList` instance to view, it works with `Html.DropDown` extension methods.